# Add and remove multiple classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add and remove multiple classes on a text field by clicking different radio buttons. I'm not able to remove the unwanted classes while switching between different radio buttons.

My code for this is:

```
// For 1st radio button
if (actionUrl == "search-client-by-id") {
    $("#req").removeClass("validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20],custom[onlyLetterSp]]")
             .addClass("validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]]");
}
// For 2nd radio button
else if (actionUrl == "search-client-by-name") {    
    $("#req").removeClass("validate[required,custom[onlyNumberSp]]")
             .addClass("validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber],maxSize[20],custom[onlyLetterSp]]");
}
```

Answer (score 345, accepted):

You can separate multiple classes with the space:

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I have found a solution for this, every time I use .removeClass() only and no need to write any class name in removeClass to remove all the added classes and add any class by choice. Yes its working...!

Comment: Using .removeClass() [with no parameters] removes all classes of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 22):

Add multiple classes:

```
$("p").addClass("class1 class2 class3");
```

or in cascade:

```
$("p").addClass("class1").addClass("class2").addClass("class3");
```

Very similar also to remove more classes:

```
$("p").removeClass("class1 class2 class3");
```

or in cascade:

```
$("p").removeClass("class1").removeClass("class2").removeClass("class3");
```

Comment: so what is you want to remove a class from multiple `$("p")`?

Comment: in my example I refer to all the paragraphs on the page but it is just an example. You can identify a specific item with an ID or another class.

Answer (score 3):

> **TL;DR**
>
> ```
> $("p").removeClass('one four').addClass("three one");
>
> // FYI: Order of addClass & removeClass can be changed too & chaining is also possible, e.g
> $("p").addClass("three one").removeClass('one four').addClass('class1 class2 class3');`
> ```

***More Working examples & details.***

```js
// handle button click & add/remove classes
$("#myBtn").click(function() {

  $("#myPara").addClass("three four").removeClass('two three');

  // again show the classes applied after we addede/remove multiple classes
  $("#container").text($("#myPara").attr("class"));
});
```

```css
.one {
  color: red;
}

.two {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.three {
  font-style: bold;
}

.four {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p id="myPara" class="one two three">hello world</p>

<p> Classes applied: <b><span id='container'>one two three</span></b></p>

<button id="myBtn">Click Me</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this
$("p").addClass("class1 class2 class3");

Comment: **This has already been mentioned in the other answers.** When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

easiest way to append class name using javascript.
It can be useful when `.siblings()` are misbehaving.

```
document.getElementById('myId').className += ' active';
```

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question, which asked explicitly for jQuery.

Comment: And you should use classList anyway