# Ajax change before and after property after submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Ajax newsletter submit in Laravel.
I want to change the mail icon into checked icon if the data passed successfully.

Ajax:

```
success: function (json) {
        
   container.find('.newsletter-notification').addClass('success').html("You've successfully subscribed to Newsletter.");
   $('.newsletter-block .newsletter-content .content button:before').css('content', '\e080');
        
},
```

css

```
.newsletter-block .newsletter-content .content button:before
{
  content: "\e01f";
  font-family: 'simple-line-icons';
}
```

How can I change *content: "\e01f"* into *content: "\e080"*

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Comment: Create two different css classes, one for each state, and swap the classes in the elements instead. It's cleaner to have all the styling in css instead of have some in css and some in js.

Comment: how can I remove class *content* from the above code in js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add and remove multiple classes in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185709/add-and-remove-multiple-classes-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try This
CSS

```
.newsletter-block .newsletter-content .content button:before
{
  content: "\e01f";
  font-family: 'simple-line-icons';
}

.newsletter-block .newsletter-content .content button.success:before
{
  content: "\e080";
  font-family: 'simple-line-icons';
}
```

Javascript

```
success: function (json) {
    var = newsLetterBtn = $('.newsletter-block .newsletter-content .content button');
    container.find('.newsletter-notification').addClass('success').html("You've successfully subscribed to Newsletter.");
    newsLetterBtn.addClass('success');
},
```